# How to connect GoogleApiComponent HOC to redux store?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a react component to display markers on map based on a list of lat/long coordinates.

Using the [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) npm package I have a Container Component and a Map component.  The MapsContainer component is wrapped in the the GoogleApiComponent HOC as follows.

```
export default GoogleApiComponent({
  apiKey: 'myapikey'
})(MapContainer);
```

What I need to now do is connect this MapContainer component to the redux store for the list of lat/long comoponents.  I've tried

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GoogleApiComponent);
```

and

```
const composeHoc = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  GoogleApiComponent
);
```

Each time I get the following warning and my map doesn't render:

`Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`

My question is: How do I connect the GoogleApiComponent HOC to my redux store?

Note: My implementation is based off of the npm package's [accompanying tutorial](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/#the-map-container-component)

Comment: Can you share codesandbox for this I think issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wrap it completely with `GoogleApiComponent`:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GoogleApiComponent({
                                        apiKey: 'myapikey'
                                       })(MapContainer));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would I do this with compose?

Comment: Compose or Recompose ? As I would suggest not to include another library for executing multiple HOCs.

Comment: I meant compose since it comes with redux.  It isn't clear to me that this is even a use case for compose - I'm about 2 weeks in to working with redux and am still getting my head around HOC's and how they work and when to use what...  Thanks for your help on this!